# bibtex: bar over a capital letter

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way to simultaneously capitalize and put a bar over a letter in BibTeX?

I know that to capitalize a letter, it needs to be wrapped in `{}`, and `\=` can be used to  put a bar over it.

But this does not seem to work together. Any ideas? Thanks much.

Comment: Try `{\={A}}` - does that work?  I would also research using `biber` instead of `bibtex` - `biber` supports unicode natively, meaning you could just input `Ā`.

Comment: Can you provide a Minimum Working Example so people can reproduce the issue? I'm probably not the only one whose .bib files will no longer work with bibtex (as opposed to biblatex/biber).

Comment: Actually, {\={A}} does work afterall: I should have recompiled everything from scratch. Problem solved, thanks a lot.

Comment: @SeanAllred If you want, write an answer or vote to close as duplicate/unclear/OT; please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved according to the comments.